# ¿Cómo cambiar "this" de una clase EC6 en javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Cuando tengo un método por ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
function person() {
    console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`)
}
person.call({ name: 'Jamie' })
```

Puedo asignar un "this" dinámico, sin embargo, cuando se trabaja con clases, no sucede de la misma manera

```
class person {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría asignar un ámbito dinámico "this" a una clase ?, algo así:

```
const p = new person()
p.prototype = { name: 'Jamie' }
```

No sabía si era específico, soy nuevo en esta clase de EC6

Comment: Hola Jamie Joao, estás en el sitio en español de Stack Overflow, por favor, traduce tu pregunta para que pueda ser reabierta. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre este sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5):

En realidad la sintaxis de ES6 (nombre oficial es ES2015) es lo que se conoce como  [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) (*Syntactic sugar* en el original).

Por tanto, [como puedes ver usando el transpilador de Babel](https://babeljs.io/en/repl.html#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa1gHsB2yATgK7BI6EAUADmIWALYCUamW0SAFgJYQB0YJIW4AjYuQC8tegwDcbAL5s2DeOQAmOAIyUWGdtnwQcIeHxA4A5pS68BQ0eJxN5WJQqA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), si defines una clase así:

```
class Test {
  constructor(param) {
    this.atributo=param;
  }

  metodo1() {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
}
```

Es equivalente a definirla así:

```
var Test = function () {
  function Test(param) {
    this.atributo = param;
  }

  Test.prototype.metodo1 = function metodo1() {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  };

  return Test;
}();
```

Esto significa que puedes modificar el contexto (this) del mismo modo:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(param) {
    this.atributo=param;
  }

  metodo1() {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
}

let t1=new Test('Patito');

t1.metodo1();

//varias formas de modificar el valor de this

t1.metodo1.call({atributo: 'Pollito'});

let funcion= t1.metodo1.bind({atributo: 'Perrito'});
funcion();

let objeto= { 
   atributo: 'Gatito',
   m: Test.prototype.metodo1
}

objeto.m();
```

Answer (score 1):

En el constructor tienes que crear la propiedad `this.name`. Por ejemplo puedes utilizar los nombres de un array.

```js
let nombres = ["Jamie","Joao"];
let personas = []

class Person {
    constructor(nombre) {
        this.name = nombre;
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}

nombres.forEach(n=>{
  personas.push(new Person(n))
})
```